# passing dynamic value to circleprogress

Tags: javascript, angular

my component.ts look like below

```
import { CircleProgressComponent, CircleProgressOptions } from 'ng-circle-progress';
percentValue: number;
this.percentValue = '90'
```

below is my compoment.html,

```
<circle-progress #circleProgress 
    [percent]="99" 
    [title]="options.title" 
    [units]="options.units">
</circle-progress>
```

**want to pass [percent] from binding, like below**

```
<circle-progress #circleProgress 
    [percent]="{percentValue}" 
    [title]="options.title" 
    [units]="options.units">
</circle-progress>
```

But this giving error and stop rendering page. 
Any idea how to pass value dynamically

Comment: Simply `[percent]="percentValue"` should do it, unless I misunderstood. Refer to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-).

Comment: can I perform some maths as well like [percent]="percentValue * 100" - its giving error

Comment: This should work. What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your percentValue is of type Number, and you are assigning a string to it.

Simply change it to this:

```
percentValue: number;
this.percentValue = 90 //Changed from '90' to 90
```

Also as the comment suggests change the HTML like

```
<circle-progress #circleProgress
      [percent]="percentValue"
      [title]="options.title"
      [units]="options.units">                  
</circle-progress>
```

Please do let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: can I perform some maths as well like [percent]="percentValue * 100" - its giving error